# How to 'group' data in excel and find the maximum in the group

Tags: excel, vba

I have parent and child accounts that make a family. If the Parent_acct = Accnt_no then its parent. I need to find the maximum Term in the family and show as Family_term (this is to be calculated) for each account. What's the good way to do it? Sorry cannot post an image yet.

```
        Parent_acct_no   Account_no    Type    Term         Family_term(max)
        565              565           Parent  45           78
        565              256           Child   78           78
        331              331           Parent  23           87
        331              754           Child   87           87
        331              823           Child   19           87
```

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Your problem will look simpler if you realize that the only columns to be considered are `Parent_acct_no` and `Term`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an array formula of max combined with if.  Assume the columns are A (Parent_Account_No) through E (Family term max), the formula in column E should be (starting with E2):

```
{=max(if($A$2:$A$6=A2,$D$2:$D$6,FALSE))}
```

Make sure to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering the formula to make it an array formula (see details here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx)

Comment: Excellent! Just for clarification. Enter the formula without the curlybrackets and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, Excel will add them by itself if its correct. Another thing, If u are using swedish the arguments to formulas are separeted by semicolon ; not ,

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the following columns:

```
A               B            C     D      E
Parent_acct_no  Account_no   Type  Term   Family_term(max)
```

And you want to sum up `Family_term` grouped by each `Type=Parent` then you could use the following formula in Column F

```
(F2) =if(c2="Parent";sumif(A$2:A$500;B2;E$2:E$500);"")
```

If you name the column A (P_acc=A$2:A$500) and E (F_term=E$2:E$500) you can write

```
(F2) =if(c2="Parent";sumif(P_acc;B2;F_term);"")
```

Since I don't have access to excel at home I could not test it tho.

Hope that helps.

*Edit: Corrected my denglish excel command (when->if) Thx.*

Comment: What's `when`?? Wait a minute... Es heißt `IF` auf English :-)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett This happens when you don't have excel at hand to test your stuff and write an answer while half asleep. Thx.

Comment: No worries. This returns the sum of `Family_term(max)` whereas the OP wants the maximum of `Term`...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Double rats. You're right again. Now I understand what the OP wanted. Good answer for the wrong question or so ;)